# Recomend a 2G/3G/4G router with two or more SIM cards

Tags: router, 3g, cellular

I'm looking for a device that takes two or more GSM SIM cards, connects over 2G/3G/4G, depending on what is available in that area, and aggregates those links for higher bandwidth and/or redundancy in case one of the cellular networks is not available.

Ideally, the device would also be a WiFi AP, with at least some rudimentary QoS services.

Googling around I've found Cisco 880 series, and it looks like it fits the bill. Are there any other devices that I should look into?

Thanks guys!

Comment: product recommendation is off-topic, see FAQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think mikrotik has some that do. No SIM support on the hardware, but USB works - i.e. you plug in a SIM MODEM on a USB hug and it can use them.

http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/archive/index.php/t-400897.html

Answer (score 2):

The [Elfiq units](http://elfiq.com/3g) can take USB 3g/4g cards and aggregate/balance connections. You'll still need a traditional router or firewall to sit behind it, though.